# Jekyll ignores css rules

Tags: jekyll

I recently revived my old Jekyll project started with Jekyll 3.x (now using Jekyll 4.2 and I forgot a lot). The generated site is OK if browsed with `jekyll serve` command, but if later I manually enter `_site` folder and click `index.html` the site ignores `css` rules and links are broken.

This makes me nervous how to deploy the site. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your site is served from a development web server when you run `jekyll serve`. I'm assuming by click `index.html`, you mean you are opening the file in your web browser - this won't work well with the absolute URLs Jekyll creates.

You can see the difference in the URL bar: one will say `http://` and the other will be `file://`, a URL like `/css/main.css` will likely only work through the web server (i.e. `jekyll serve`).

Assuming you are deploying the site to a web server, and it works with `jekyll serve`, I'd guess it's fine. I can't be sure, but in any case, You should probably back up what's on the server currently though so you can restore it.